# выполнение программы

Tags: c++, область-видимости

```
extern int x; // здесь мы объявляем переменную без её определения

int main()
{
    std::cout << x; 
}

static int x = 4; // здесь её определение
```

как это работает, если выполнение программы ещё не дошло до её определения?

```
int main()
{
    extern int x;
    {
        std::cout << x;
    }
    int x = 4;
}
```

Тогда почему это не работает?

Comment: Будет работать, если без `static` определять, т.к. инициализация ещё до `main` выполняется.

Comment: так оно и со static работает

Comment: Не должно, т.к. переобъявление переменной с internal linkage после external. Скорее всего, у вас `msvc` с нестандартным расширением.

Comment: `extern` можно использовать только для глобальных переменных

Comment: @КоржикБогатырский не только, см. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/extern.

Answer (score 2):

Тут не работает ни первый вариант, ни второй. Оба - так как не объявлен `std`. А первый - еще так как переменная `x` объявляется сначала с external linkage, а затем с internal linkage. Второй не работает, так как локальная переменная `x` объявляется после предварительного объявления `extern` переменной с тем же именем.

Работающие варианты выглядит вот так:

```
#include <iostream>

extern int x;
int main()
{
    ::std::cout << ::x;
}
int x = 4;
```

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    extern int x;
    ::std::cout << x;
}
int x = 4;
```

Answer (score 2):

Первый вариант не работает: `<source>:10:12: error: static declaration of 'x' follows non-static declaration`.

Потому что на определении есть `static`, а на объявлении нет. Невозможно объявить static-переменную (снаружи класса), не определяя ее, поэтому тут остается только убрать static.

Глобальные переменные создаются до захода в main. Учитывайте, что если `x` - не `static`, то она может быть вообще в другом файле.

Во втором варианте, `extern int x;` объявляет несуществующую глобальную переменную. Локальную переменную тоже нельзя объявить не определяя.